# How to import a symbol from a DLL

Tags: visual-studio

I've got two projects in a VS2019 solution. One is a DLL and one an console EXE which should import symbols from the DLL. I want to do that wighout __declspec(dllexport) / __declspec(dllimport). With the DLL I have a .DEF-file which says which symboles are to be EXPORTed. When I look at the .lib- or the DLL-file with DUMPBIN /exports I get shown the correct exports. AFAIK I only need to declare the external functions in the EXE and have the .lib-file in my EXE-project linker-settings. But that doesn't work - my linker says that there's a missing external symbol in the .OBJ- as well as the .EXE-file. How do I prepare the EXE-project correctly ?

There were times before __declspec(dllexport) / __declspec(dllexport) and in this ages I only used .DEF-files and imported the symbols via a .lib as I described above. But that was about when I used NT 3.1 in the first half of the 90s. So I'm pretty sure this should work like I had it before today also.

The Code in the DLL looks like this:

```
extern "C"
{
    char const *helloString;
}
```

The code in the EXE looks like this:

```
extern "C"
char const *helloString;
```

The .DEF-file looks like this:

```
LIBRARY Dll
EXPORTS
    helloString DATA
```

As I said everythin on the DLL-side seems ok, i.e. DUMBIN shows the proper symbol for the .lib- and .dll-file.

Comment: nowadays you probably should use `#pragma comment(lib, "yourlib.lib")` instead, then just have a header for your dll. If you insist on .def files dont forget to use the decorated names of the functions. or declare them as extern "C" if you prefer C linkage.

Comment: I already added the additional include directorys to point to the build-output-dir ($(IntDir)) and I added the .lib-file in the lib-list. And the linker honors this setting because I checked that by adding a non-existing .lib and then I get an error. So everything should be complete. I just want to keep the sources completely free of any linkage-specific settings so that I can use the same code for static linking.

Comment: The missing external symbol.. is that something that is supposed to be in your dll? or is it something else? Also you have not said if your code is C++ or C and if both are in the same language since this affects linkage it is important to know.